# Why does my smtp request keep timing out in python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to use smtp to send emails in python but I keep getting the error:

```
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

this is the code I am using to send the message:

```
connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
connection.starttls()
connection.login(user=my_email, password=my_password)
connection.sendmail(
        from_addr=my_email,
        to_addrs="RECIPIENT",
        msg="Subject:Motivational quote\n\n" + quote)
```

I have tried making sure that the email and password are correct, and I have enabled unsecured apps through Gmail, but am still unsure as to why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SMTP_SSL instead

```
try:
    connection = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    connection.ehlo()
    connection.login(user=my_email, password=my_password)
    connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email,
        to_addrs="RECIPIENT",
        msg="Subject:Motivational quote\n\n" + quote))
    connection.close()

    print 'Email sent!'
except Exception as e:
    print e
```